# Why does assigning a sliced numpy array to another variable keep slicing it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variables

I've been experiencing some strange behavior with numpy arrays. Consider the code below:

```
import numpy as np

# 1
a = [np.arange(16)]
b = a
print(f'b = {b}')

# 2
b[0] = a[0][::2]
print(f'b = {b}')

# 3
b[0] = a[0][::2]
print(f'b = {b}')
```

```
b = [array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]
b = [array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14])]
b = [array([ 0,  4,  8, 12])]
```

I'd expect `b` in section 2 to be the same as the `b` in section 3, but for some reason it seems to be different. This doesn't seem to happen when `a` is a 1D array—writing `b = a[::2]` twice gives the same value for `b`. Why is this happening when `a` is a 2D array?

Comment: `a` is *not* a 2D array. You made a list with an array inside.

Comment: It is working as designed. You are asking `b[0]` to be reassigned to every other value of `a`. Remember, you defined `b = a` so both `b` and `a` are same lists. Just referenced.

Comment: Also, `b = a` doesn't make a copy.

Comment: @JoeFerndz: `b` and `a` are the same list. They're not arrays.

Comment: I see, seems like an elementary mistake. But then why doesn't this happen when `a = np.arange(16)`? Is there something fundamentally different between a list and an array?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, yes. correct. corrected my response.

Comment: @SkeletonBow no, it *always* works the same way. That is simply the semantics of assignment in python, regardless of type

Comment: There's a big difference between assigning `b = a[:2]` (`a` is an array) and `b[0] = a[0][:2]`  (`a` is list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have given `b = a`  So `b` is just making a reference of `a`. Every time you change the value of `b`, you are also making a change to value of `a`. For more details on assignment vs copy vs deep copy, please refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@thawsitt/assignment-vs-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-python-f70c2f0ebd86)

```
b[0] = a[0][::2]
```

The above code is asking b to have skipped values of `b` (`a` is same as `b`). So every time you do this, it is reducing it further.

If you want to make a copy, use

```
b = a.copy()
```

or

```
b = a[::]
```

Comment: So why doesn't this happen with `a = np.arange(16)`? It seems as though `b` *isn't* made a reference of `a` if `a` is a numpy array?

Comment: `np.arange() Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.` Here, you are just calling a numpy function to create an evenly spaced values. `b=a` is assignment of two variables. In this case you just make the reference of b and a as same.